# CSS parent height in percentage for absolute positioned children in responsive web design

Tags: web, responsive-design, css-position

I'am actually working on a responsive design and i'm quite stuck:

I need to set image-type children position to absolute in their div parent, and keep the lower section under this parent. But actually, the only solution i have is to set a fixed height for this parent (in that case, a relative margin for the lower section wouldn't work in a dynamic structure). The problem is that the images, set to max-width: 100%; to keep their dimensions flexible, expand with the page, and the lower section is no more well positioned on resize:

```
<div id='page'>
<div id='b0'><img /><img /></div>
<section id='s0'><h2>section title</h2><p>hjkhjkhjk</p></section>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#page{max-width:1024px; margin: 0 auto;}
#b0{position: relative; height:25%;}/* doesn't work, 100px instead work but responsive design fails */
#b0 img{position: absolute;}
```

Does anyone have a solution for that ?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1):

Simplier solution :

Consists in setting each image to position: absolute; except the last one :

```
#b0 img:last-child{position: relative;
```

keeping an element in the "flood" provides its parent the needed height value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I now have a very simple mixed solution using Both CSS and Javascript:
As the primary need is "mobile first" design, i've introduced un min-height for the images container in a smartphoine targeted media query css file:

In the head tag:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width:320px)' type='text/css' href='css/css.css' />
```

Then the CSS:

```
#b0{position: relative; min-height:82px;}
```

And a little bit of Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){window.onresize=function(){$('#b0').css({'height' :( this.innerWidth * .25)+'px'})}});
```

So this mixed solution needs Javascript activated, a min-height to be set up for each media query step, and a percentage for the container height calculated with global and maximum page dimensions: in my case:

```
#page{max-width: 1024px;}
```

and a container height at about 280px;

Hope this can help someone someday ;-)